# How to change the background of a Text View in the storyboard of xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, background, textview, storyboard

I am running into a problem in xcode storyboard to setup the graphics of an app.
Nothing complicated, but I seriously don't understand the logic.

1. Import an image view that will be the background. It is set as opaque, alpha = 1, it uses an image found on internet and the background is "default". It covers the whole iphone surface
2. Import a text view. Now I am trying to have the background colour of the text view white.
   To do that, on the "Text Field" section, I have tried to use an image of white, found on the internet, no success. I have also tried in the "View" section to set the "Background" to white colour with alpha=1 and opaque activated, no success, the text view background looks exactly like the background picture, it does not stand out.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonders, I have been able to solve this programmatically using code lines like :

```
 myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Still not sure why it does not work on the interface builder though.